# TFS not displaying task board

Tags: tfs

My tfs server still displays the my work items in the "work items" list but does not display any work items on the taskboard. It uses the correctly path(Version1/Sprint1) but it tells me that there are no work items.

> tfs the task board cannot be displayed because it is empty

Does anyone got a solution for my problem?

Comment: please provide more informations (screens) for your iterations, area path and teams, without any more informations it's hard to provide a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: The backlog item which was assigned to the work items was deleted.